# Bootstrap 3 callouts missing in Yii 2 application

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, yii, yii2

I've added an example code for displaying Bootstrap 3's callout to my Yii2-powered application:

```
<div class="bs-callout bs-callout-info">
    <h4>Use protocol</h4>
    Avoid links without <code>http://www.</code> or <code>https://www.</code> in the beginning.
</div>
```

And I can't see proper styling.

What am I missing. Bootstrap on board Yii2 is to old and doesn't have these styles? Or maybe I forgot to push the magic button somewhere?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Callouts are used in their docs, but it's not included in main CSS**. Yii 2 ships with the newest version of Bootstrap (at the current moment **3.3.4**), so this is not the reason.

You have to write proper CSS styles by yourself. According to [this article](http://cpratt.co/twitter-bootstrap-callout-css-styles/) you need to add this:

```
.bs-callout {
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 20px 0;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    border-left-width: 5px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.bs-callout h4 {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.bs-callout p:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.bs-callout code {
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.bs-callout+.bs-callout {
    margin-top: -5px;
}
.bs-callout-default {
    border-left-color: #777;
}
.bs-callout-default h4 {
    color: #777;
}
.bs-callout-primary {
    border-left-color: #428bca;
}
.bs-callout-primary h4 {
    color: #428bca;
}
.bs-callout-success {
    border-left-color: #5cb85c;
}
.bs-callout-success h4 {
    color: #5cb85c;
}
.bs-callout-danger {
    border-left-color: #d9534f;
}
.bs-callout-danger h4 {
    color: #d9534f;
}
.bs-callout-warning {
    border-left-color: #f0ad4e;
}
.bs-callout-warning h4 {
    color: #f0ad4e;
}
.bs-callout-info {
    border-left-color: #5bc0de;
}
.bs-callout-info h4 {
    color: #5bc0de;
}
```

anywhere into your CSS styles.

Then you can use callouts like that:

```
<div class="bs-callout bs-callout-success">
  <h4>Success Callout</h4>
  This is a success callout.
</div>
```

Comment: I wonder why they did not include this. I find it amazingly handy to use. They have of course `Alerts`. But I prefer the callout's.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/alerts/